# How to debug CDAP sandbox with IntelliJ on mac

Tags: docker, virtualbox, remote-debugging, cdap

I am trying to debug CDAP code and plugin code

I have tried several options to run the CDAP sandbox:

https://docs.cask.co/cdap/5.1.0-SNAPSHOT/en/developer-manual/getting-started/sandbox/docker.html

The sandbox runs and the stout logs say port 5005 is exposed for debugging

```
Starting CDAP Sandbox ...Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

docker ps has two other ports:
0.0.0.0:11011->11011/tcp, 0.0.0.0:11015->11015/tcp   cdap-sandbox

When I configure IntelliJ debugger to 11015 it seems to have no problem but breakpoints don't catch the running of code.

I tried running CDAP sandbox on virtualbox and using 192.168.99.100 but I still cant catch breakpoints with the remote debugger

I also tried adding 5005 to exposed docker ports 0.0.0.0:5005->5005/tcp
 and configuring intellij to do the same. Intellij was not able to connect to remote 5005

How do I debug cdap sandbox with intellij?

Answer (score 3):

Problem is with the [functions.sh](https://github.com/cdapio/cdap/blob/98ec972a41b39acb696f3f4eb6f08c46b51fd18a/cdap-common/bin/functions.sh#L1458) file in bin directory. By default it binds the listening port to localhost.

To fix it:

Find the line:

`"CDAP_SDK_OPTS+=" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:${__port},server=y,suspend=n"`

and change it to something like (remove `localhost:`):

`"CDAP_SDK_OPTS+=" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=${__port},server=y,suspend=n"`

Comment: I haven't touched CDAP in a long while and so can't evaluate your answer.

Comment: added a link to github source, so it would be more simple to understand

Comment: While I'm not the original asker -- this was the missing piece for me.  After editing that functions.sh file, I was able to connect my remote debugger into a docker container.

Answer (score 1):

Have you started CDAP with --enable-debug flag?

Our documentation [here](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/5.1.0/en/developer-manual/testing/debugging.html#debugging-an-application-in-cdap-sandbox) will help you with starting CDAP in debug mode.

Additionally you might find our [Testing and Debugging](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/5.1.0/en/developer-manual/testing/index.html) documentation helpful.

Comment: I read the documentation it the link in my question. The debugger doesn't attach. The only way I could debug was using tests.

Answer (score 1):

- Start the CDAP sandbox in debug mode.

```
bin/cdap sandbox start --enable-debug
```

- In intelliJ goto `Run -> Edit Configurations -> Add New Configuration -> Remote`
- Specify the Configuration name, enter the host and port(5005 for debugging cdap).
- Select your maven module in *Use module classpath* input configuration and hit *Apply*
- Now to debug hit the **debug** button and you are good to go.